# iOS & Armadillo ( mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator)

Tags: ios, xcode, armadillo

I'm trying to build `iOS app` and I have to link `Armadillo`. `Xcode` can compile and build with no issue and run simulator but getting `mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator` and waiting on launch screen....

Searched around a week but no luck. Even looked all topics.

UPDATE:

I fixed my problem.

Included Armadillo and removed .dylib.

Then;

```
#define ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER
#include <armadillo>
```

Now working with no issue with simulator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that happens because your library `Armadillo` is not compiled for ARMv7, ARMv7s, ARM64 architectures, for some reason. That's why you cannot run it on iOS Devices, Mach-O is usually a linker error.

You can double check it in the terminal with `lipo`.

You have to get compiled `Armadillo` with those architectures, or source code and compile it for yourself.

Comment: Checked it with lipo and architecture is x86_64. 

How to install for iOS?

Comment: Maybe something more complex is going on.  I suggest pressing Command-< then highlighting the Diagnostics tab, then clicking Dynamic Linker API Usage and Dynamic Library Loads options.  Run the app and search for anything to do with Armadillo in the logs.  Do you see anything interesting in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Updated my question and added fix.

Comment: Rather than updating your question, you can simply add your update/fix as an answer, and mark it as such. (You can answer your own questions.)

Comment: Any one using Armadillo for iOS swift ??